# Style children of children together

Tags: css, less

I have 3 buttons that are grouped 1 seperate from the other two but I want to Style them as if they were all children of the same div.

https://codepen.io/naomilea/pen/jdEojJ

```css
.button-group {
  display: inline-flex;
  *[class^="ics-"] {
    border: 1px solid gray;
    padding: 5px 8px;
  }
  *[class^="ics-"] {
    +[class^="ics-"] {
      margin-left: -1px
    }
    &:first-child {
      border-radius: 6px 0 0 6px
    }
    &:last-child {
      border-radius: 0 6px 6px 0
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<span class="fr hover-click button-group" style="cursor: pointer;">
<i class="ics-subtract"></i>
<div style="margin-left: 0px;">
<span class="ics-drag"></span>
<span style="cursor: pointer;">
<i class="ics-trash"></i>
</span>
</div>
</span>
```

The aim is for them to look like this

[image]

```
but sometimes it will only be two buttons or even one so I need to style them in a
```

general way and not each individual button. Is there a way I can do this.

This is what I've managed to do so far
[image]

I have also tried first-of-type and it doesn't work either

Comment: You need to use `:first-child` and `:last-child` for this and you have used it too.

Comment: but it's still only counting the ics grouped in the same div and not all children.

Comment: Wait, why have you got it in different divs? or containers? And your codepen lacks the icon styles (or the font CSS), which makes it weird.

Comment: They are different components. Can't be moved.

Comment: Can you add the necessary CSS?

Comment: I can add all the CSS that is needed. I have provided all the relevant code in the codepen

Comment: Yea, please waiting for your updated codepen... All I see is this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/S5hYU.png

Comment: That is all the relevant code you need. The icons themselves is from our own library so they wont be displayed.

Comment: Ahh, alright...

Comment: Is it at least possible for you to get the `div` out of the `span` or make the parent of `div` not a span? Not a great idea to put `block` level elements inside `inline` ones.

Comment: that should be possible but I dont think that will fix the problem?

Comment: No I was just trying to re-create the CSS so... Alright... Lemme try something.

Comment: Can you change one more thing as well, the `span` with `ics` class. Can that be moved like `span` with cursor pointer and `i` with the class inside the span?

Comment: Can you post a code snippet because I dont understand what you mean

Comment: why would you write HTML like that.. It looks horrible & doesn't follow any standard, its going to be hard to manage the app as it scales.

Comment: Exactly, it's kinda getting bad... Trying to refactor.

Comment: @Naomi This is what I have so far: https://jsbin.com/fonehomubo/1/edit

Comment: It's not actually written like that, it's a snippet from react components. It's simply to show how it is structured. The question is CSS related not HTML related.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't restructure the HTML (I would if I could)

Comment: It's far from getting it fixed.

Comment: I should be able to target all children in the span though no or does the first and last child only work in the same wrapper?

Answer (score 0):

Got it fixed this way. Was a crazy way of doing but would strongly suggest you to change the component.

LESS here:

```
.button-group {
  line-height: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  padding: 0;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  border-radius: 6px;
  overflow: hidden;
  span, div {
    line-height: 0;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    padding: 0;
  }
  *[class^="ics-"] {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    border-left: 1px solid gray;
    padding: 5px 8px;
    margin-left: -1px;
  }
}
```

```css
.button-group {
  line-height: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  padding: 0;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  border-radius: 6px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.button-group span,
.button-group div {
  line-height: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.button-group *[class^="ics-"] {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  border-left: 1px solid gray;
  padding: 5px 8px;
  margin-left: -1px;
}
```

```html
<div class="fr hover-click button-group" style="cursor: pointer;">
  <i class="ics-subtract"></i>
  <div style="margin-left: 0px;">
    <span class="ics-drag"></span>
    <span style="cursor: pointer;">
      <i class="ics-trash"></i>
    </span>
  </div>
</div>
```